# Export Python Dataframe to Excel

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export a Python Dataframe to excel using xlsx or csv...

Here is the code I tried to use:

```
    export_word_count = word_count.to_excel (r'C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\word_count.xlsx', index = None, header=True)
```

I keep getting the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/OTR/PycharmProjects/MyProjects/CAP_Test_MotsCles.py", line 35, 
in <module>
export_word_count = word_count.to_excel 
(r'C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\word_count_CAP.xlsx', index = None, 
header=True)
File "C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2127, in to_excel
engine=engine)
File "C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 656, in write
writer = ExcelWriter(_stringify_path(writer), engine=engine)
File "C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 1204, in __init__
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

Any output on this would be greatly appreciated. I tried to tweek the code, but still wouldn't export. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Managed to export, but having issues with full data export

*Sample Python Data*:

```
products          58
company           53
cannabis          42
business          39
```

Comment: pip install openpyxl

Comment: There is something wrong with your installation, which seems to be missing the openpyxl library. Try installing it separately. To export it via a csv, use df.to_csv().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have python openpyxl module installed.
Install it with:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: I just did, it managed to export. However, my export is a list of most commun words in my dataframe. It only exported the frequency of the words, without the words themselves. So for example, I get : products          58
company           53 ........ but in excel, I get 58 53.

Comment: Can you please provide sample of dataframe that you want to export ?

Comment: The words themselves are probably your index. So instead remove the argument ‘index = None’.

Comment: Klemen, I've provided a sample, but Niels Henkens provided me with the right answer. Thank you all so much for your answers! It did work at last :) It was the index = None that was removing the words.

Comment: For those who use the conda distribution (Anaconda or Miniconda), the equivalent is writing in the Anaconda Prompt `conda install openpyxl`

Answer (score 0):

Your words are your index. Right now you are not exporting the index. 
Try changing your code to:

```
word_count.to_excel (r'C:\Users\OTR\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\word_count.xlsx', index =True, header=True)
```

‘index=True’ is the default behavior, so not actually necessary.